# update Android provider.Settings.System value

Tags: android, system, settings.settings

it seen i can't write to settings in LG-P500 (Android 2.2).
This is my code:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 1);
```

Value to specify if the user prefers the date, time and time zone to be automatically fetched from the network (NITZ). 1=yes, 0=no

It work fine in my emulator android 2.2
I also try in other phone, HTC android 2.1 it works fine too.

Could anyone know what would be the problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

This should do the trick ;-)

Comment: i try that one too.. it works in HTC Hero,but still not working in LG Optimus one..

Comment: I am on LG Optimus One and this works.. check your code, maybe you forgot some intent filters in Manifest..

Comment: The permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is only allowed to the system apps.